# Can we use localbroadcast receiver to communicate between activity and service?

Tags: android, localbroadcastmanager

Hello I am working on android application where I want to use `LocalBroadCastManager`. I want to perform network operation in service and send result to activity from there using `LocalBroadCastManager`.

Is it possible to do that using `LocalBroadCastManager` or Do  I have to do same in different method ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: imo it's actually I good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can !
But be sure to not use this service in another process !
Check your manifest and see if where you declared your service you haven't used the tag `android:process`, if you haven't you are good to go !

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a reason to do the network operation in a service, you should take a look at [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html),  or even [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/)